# Linux TCP/IP Diagnosing Why TCP/IP read() Returns 0 in C Program

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a number of C programs running on a Linux host (RHEL 6.6).  They have TCP/IP connections to other applications on the same host.  There is very little traffic over each connection.  Every once in awhile, a read() call on one of the sockets to a process on the same host returns 0.  These sockets are normally kept up for the lifetime of the application, so they are not cleanly closed during normal operations.  I would expect that if an error occurs such as the other end crashing, the read() will return -1 and set errno.

So, the question is - is there any reason other than the TCP/IP connection being closed cleanly (shutdown(fd); close(fd)) by the other end that would cause the read() call to return 0?

The man page for read() states that 0 is only returned for EOF, while the recv() man page states it returns "0 when the peer has performed an orderly shutdown".  I'd assume that the return from read() and recv() would be equivalent, and EOF on a TCP/IP connection implies a clean shutdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, the question is - is there any reason other than the TCP/IP
>   connection being closed cleanly (shutdown(fd); close(fd)) by the other
>   end that would cause the read() call to return 0

For starters the process dying would free up the file descriptor which would have the same effect: a clean connection close.

> I would expect that if an error occurs such as the other end crashing,
>   the read() will return -1 and set errno.

It depends what you mean by "crashes". If the process for example dies but the OS is still fine, then as far as TCP is concerned everything is OK and it can just close the connection for the now-orphaned socket (same as above in other words).

---

Side note: there are of course ways in which your `recv` can return `-1` because of a misbehaving peer (for example the peer can force a TCP reset).

Comment: I believe Windows resets an open socket when the process exists, but Unix and Linux certainly close it properly.

Comment: This is exactly what was happening - the application on the other end crashed and Linux cleanly shut things down.